# Replace old records while inserting new duplicate records in Mongoose

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoose, insert-update

The mongoDB collection:

db.collection.find()

```
 { _id:'...', emp: 'A', name: 'nameA', age: 23 }
 { _id:'...', emp: 'B', name: 'nameB', age: 54 }
 { _id:'...', emp: 'C', name: 'nameC', age: 45 }
```

The data which are inserted in the collection:

```
 { _id:'...', emp: 'D', name: 'nameA', age: 22 }
 { _id:'...', emp: 'B', name: 'nameB1', age: 34 }
 { _id:'...', emp: 'A', name: 'nameA1', age: 47 }
 { _id:'...', emp: 'E', name: 'nameE', age: 23 }
```

The duplicated **emp** row's data will be replaced with newly added values.
The output after inserting the new data in collection:

```
 { _id:'...', emp: 'A', name: 'nameA1', age: 47 }
 { _id:'...', emp: 'B', name: 'nameB1', age: 34 }
 { _id:'...', emp: 'C', name: 'nameC', age: 45 }
 { _id:'...', emp: 'D', name: 'nameD', age: 22 }
 { _id:'...', emp: 'E', name: 'nameE', age: 23 }
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: When adding new records to the collection, the duplicated emp rows values will be replaced with new ones.

Comment: So I assume the `emp` field is not a unique value and you want there to be multiple objects with `emp: 'A'` instead of having them deleted?
The deletion usually occurs when you have an issue with constraints on given fields.
Can you provide the function where you call the database to insert new objects?

Comment: I want to replace the old emp: 'A' with the new name and age values. And I am using the basic insert method for inserting the new data.

Comment: use update with upsert option

Answer (score 0):

Specify `upsert: true` in the update options.

Insert case:

```js
db.collection.update({
  emp: "E"
},
{
  $set: {
    name: "nameE",
    age: 23
  },
  "$setOnInsert": {
    _id: 5,
    emp: "E"
  }
},
{
  upsert: true
})
```

[Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pEZ2bH4OCT9)

update case:

```js
db.collection.update({
  emp: "A"
},
{
  $set: {
    name: "nameA1",
    age: 47
  },
  "$setOnInsert": {
    _id: 1,
    emp: "A"
  }
},
{
  upsert: true
})
```

[Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NJiSxFzHPxI)